# Code Lens does not display the name of the person last edited

Tags: visual-studio, codelens

I'm using:

- Microsoft Visual Studio Community 2019, Version 16.6.5
- and Git that connect to AzureDevops as source control.

For some reason, the Code Lens feature does not show me the last person who updated the method.

Here is what I see:
[image]

Any ideas on how to display the name of the person last edited a method?

Answer (score 0):

Looks like it's because I am using the Community version which doesn't have all the features of CodeLens https://visualstudio.microsoft.com/vs/compare/

[image]